# Passing value to PHP variable inside script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have some PHP code inside the script so I need
the JavaScript value as a PHP variable, as follows:

```
<script>
;
 var js_var = 123;
 var php_var = <?php js_var ?>;
 alert(php_var);
;
</script>
```

Using jQuery to send the value to a PHP page will return the value but not as a PHP variable:

```
$.get("page.php", {js_var_name: js_var}, function(data) {alert(data)});
```

I tried also all jQuery AJAX functions: load(), post() and the ajax() method, none of them pass back the value of PHP as above requested.

Is it possible to implement the above with jQuery?

Comment: I don't understand the problem... could you please provide a better example?

Comment: look in browser source... what shows up for `var php_var =` ?

Comment: What exactly do you expect `<?php js_var ?>` to do? Try `echo` or `print` and using the `$` variable prefix.

Comment: var js_var represent the value from the pressed radio button (123).
I want to store this number, in the same script, as PHP variable (php_var) so that I can use it later in another PHP function.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the client/server architecture this stuff is based on. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-code-in-my-javascript-not-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely you have a syntax issue with :

```
var php_var = <?php js_var ?>;
```

Unless you used `define()` your php variable should start with `$` and you need to echo it so that it gets printed to the page

```
var php_var = <?php echo $js_var ?>;
```

If you are assuming that php will read the prior javascript `js_var=123` it won't. Javscript is a client side language and php is server side.

Comment: I understand that PHP will not read the prior JavaScript js_var=123, but is it possible to store the number 123 as a PHP variable inside JavaScript.

Comment: are you using `$_GET['js_var_name']` to receive the value from AJAX in php? Really not clear what the issue is

Comment: @user203952: At the moment when the JavaScript is executed, PHP does not exist anymore... that's why I find you question confusing. You can of course send the value of a variable back to the server and keep in a variable there... is that what you want to do?

Comment: @ Felix Kling, thank you for this information because I didn’t know that when JavaScript is executed, PHP does not exist anymore. My problem is how do I get back the variable from the server and use it in another PHP function inside the script.

Comment: use the AJAX you are using to send data to server

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply mix PHP and JavaScript. The former is executed on the server, the latter on the client, namely in the user's browser. In order to hand a value from PHP to JavaScript you need to output JavaScript code via PHP or do a AJAX-Request to a PHP-Script, as you tried. When using AJAX, it is the easiest solutions to have PHP script that returns a JSON string. When calling this script using `$.get()` the result will be stored in a JavaScript variable and you can access all the values from there.

Take a moment and a deep breath...and then start thinking about your scopes again.